# UAA not working for Front End NodeJS application

Tags: cloudfoundry-uaa, predix

I created service instance for UAA in Predix Console. In Predix Toolkit, I created user using clientID. I replaced configurations in localConfig.json:
[image]

I double checked in Predix Toolkit for token checking it shows me a json format with list of values with no error response code. I bound uaa service to an app. I checked in my browser app is not redirecting to UAA for authenticating user.

Answer (score 0):

Your front end app will need to do the redirection to UAA.  What front end app are you using?  If your app is based on the predix-seed, and you use the configuration above, then it should redirect to UAA for you.  Predix seed app is available here:

https://github.com/predixdev/predix-seed

This app uses the Predix Passport library to handle UAA authentication.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @gstroup. I am using https://github.com/PredixDev/predix-nodejs-starter - application to bind with UAA.

Comment: predix-nodejs-starter works almost the same way.  With this application, you're not automatically redirected to login.  You should see the index.html page, and you should see links to login or view secure page.  What behavior do you see??